# PostgreSQL Trim created_at timestamp column values function pg_catalog.btrim(timestamp without time zone) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, performance

In our PostgreSQL we have created_at column and it has a lot of data inserted as a 
timestamp.

Now while we are fetching data using 

`explain analyze select * from users where created_at > '2018-01-01 11:02:03'::timestamp`

and it got tooo many time

So `trim()` of these values is it possbile

```
like created_at > trim('2018-01-01 11:02:03')
```

Please help me

or `update users set created_at = trim(created_at)` not working

how to trim created_at as a timestamp not date it gave error while I trim all created_at `function pg_catalog.btrim(timestamp without time zone) does not exist`

Thanks

why I want to Trim created_at timestamp column

as Some of the columns I did trim and it found indexed scan and make select much faster.

But In created_at I am not able to make it faster I though after trim() It will do indexed scan instead of sequential scan

Comment: If you don't want a time, user the `date` data type. Otherwise, please explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe how to trim created_at as a timestamp not date it gave error while I trim all created_at ` function pg_catalog.btrim(timestamp without time zone) does not exist`

Comment: you probably are looking for `date_trunc` or want to cast date from timestamp?..

Comment: date_trunc change the timestamp to another correct me if I am wrong @Vao Please make a post

Comment: yes - it does. I'm trying to guess what you want to achieve. please post clear data sample and expected result.

Comment: I want to make it faster as some of the column I did trim and it got index scan search but created_at not able to trim and it goes to seq_scan can you suggest

Answer (score 0):

If you do a simple :

```
SELECT to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

You will get a string of the date.

```
SELECT to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date;
```

Will return a date.

Now, if your problem is a perfomance problem, you should make an index on your created_at field.

```
CREATE INDEX ON users (created_at);
explain analyze select * from users where created_at > '2018-01-01';
```

Should be really quicker.